# Migrated app from 32bit to 64bit testing

Tags: c++, testing, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I need to test a C++ application that is ported from 32bit to 64bit. I intend to test following scenarios:

1 - Test it should be a *real* 64bits app (couldnot run on 32bit system; only could run on 64bit system)

2 - Data handling/storing

3 - Migrated app should maintain the same functionalities with the 32bit one.

4 - Memory handling/leakage

Question:

1 - Do 4 above tests are enough for 32bit-to-62bit migration testing

2 - What I should test for 2nd test (Data handling/storing). I just have idea, but donot know exact cases I need to care

3 - What we should expect from an apps in 64bit suppored compared to 32bit supported in memory perspective

Appreciate your guidance

Comment: To answer your third question, 64-bit apps can utilize more than 4 GB of memory while 32-bit apps can't

Comment: 32-bit apps can sometimes with some OS extension (possibly a windowing method) access more than 4GB of memory but it tends to be more difficult because you still have only a 4GB address space the OS extension does not make the pointers bigger then 32 bits.

Comment: A question should include a single specific programming problem. Create separate questions if you have multiple questions - don't combine them.

Comment: There is no cookie-cutter recipe, no magic button one can push and be guaranteed of a thorough regression testing coverage. Every application is unique, and different. Nobody on stackoverflow.com has any idea what your application is all about, what it does, and how it works. Vague generalities are only good for making vague, general proclamation that might be found useful by some PHB, but have absolutely no tangible value, whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any third party library's or DLL's you'll need to get the 64 bit versions.